# Knitr automatically comments lines of code

Tags: r, knitr

I want to present and execute several (let's say 10) lines of code, but the 10-th line produces warning. I want to suppress it, but if I put it within `suppressWarnings()`, this will be shown too.

My idea to fix this:

- I leave the 10-th line as it is, but I remove it from evaluation.
- I add 11-th line with `suppressWarnings()` that will be executed, but hidden.

So, my chunk looks like

`<<chunk, echo=c(1:10), eval=c(1:9,11)>>=`

And it works, aside of one thing: it puts two `#` symbols before the line that's not evaluated (but supposed to be shown normally!) so it's actually within comment =(

`## plot(...)`

Any idea how to change this?

Comment: I know that I can add `warning=FALSE` in chunk settings, but sometimes I can still want to show the lines, which are not necessarily executed. How can I do this?

Comment: Setting `opts_chunk$set(comment=NA)` will remove the `##`. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @ruaridhw I pasted it into the chunk, but it doesn't seem to work, I still see `##`. Maybe I am using this in a wrong way?

Comment: You need to either put that line in its own chunk at the start of the script (see the knitr documentation) or use `comment=NA` as a chunk option if it only applies to this one chunk. The former option is universal

Comment: I tried to put it in its own chunk, in the chunk I calculate stuff in, add `comment=NA` into given chunk options, but none of these works. Here's an example:
 `    <<example, echo=c(1:3), warning=FALSE, comment=NA, eval=c(1:2)>>=`
 `   opts_chunk$set(comment=NA)`
   ` n = 50 `
  `  mm = 2000`
`    @`

Edit: not sure how to write code and make new lines in comments, looks like multiple inline codes, one after another, don't work properly :/

Comment: `comment=NA` applies to code *output* such as `head(mtcars)` as opposed to unevaluated lines within a chunk.

Comment: Ahh, this way. Thank you!